# How to Create static Page for navigation bar in custom wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I have a Home Page(index.php) in my custom wordpress page . In Home page i have a horizontal navigation bar where i have a "contact us" section since i am new to wordpress development i dont know how to create contact us in wordpress.

code of my contact us page is

```
<?php/* This is contact page of SampleTheme */
?>

<?php
get_header();
?>
<div class="EventCalender">  <?php echo do_shortcode(' [do_widget id=spider_calendar-2]'); ?> <br>
<p class="EventCalenderPara"> There are  13 Planed events!! We all hope<br>
to see you and your family there! </p></div>
<?php get_footer(); /?>
```

when i run this page by runing url "localhost/wordpress/contact.php" i am getting 404 error. I have only index,header,footer,function,contact pages in my custom wordpress theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"localhost/wordpress/contact.php" -- It is wrong. you can create a new contact page then run this url "localhost/wordpress/contact" if your contact page name is "contact"
If you want to create custom page follow this
 use  this top of your contact.php page

`<?php 
/* Template Name:Contact*/ 
?>`

Then go to dashboard -> pages -> **edit** contact page (if not exist create a new page) -> from right sidebar click template name and choose Contact. save and run

Comment: Thanx for Your Replay Sir . sir page is working but url is "http://Localhost/wordpress/index.php/sample-page/contact/" , I want url "http://Localhost/wordpress/index.php/contact/" . Please advice how i can edit this url of Contact page.

Comment: Here you have a parent page(Sample Page). In editor, page attribute section make it to "no parent". From right side of editor go to "Parent" ->click dropdown -> click "no parent". After that url should be "Localhost/wordpress/index.php/contact/"

Comment: Sir , I am facing a issue that now the page which i am developing as contact page has become index.php (home page). it is also working with url "Localhost/wordpress" and "Localhost/wordpress/index.php" ... please help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: copy index.php and rename it home.php that will show your home page only. and please read wordpress page structure. everything will be clear.